# How do I 'scale' the UI to a readable size

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-theming

When I display my app on a device, the fonts, icons and buttons are unusably small. This is especially true on a tablet.

How can I easily scale up all of of my UI components?

Comment: Have you made sure to define all sizes in em instead of px? I have all sizes in my theme in em and I'm not having this issue.

Comment: I've done no styling at all. All of the styles are the defaults. The issue I have applies to the size of buttons as well as text, so although I can go through all of the CSS and make each individual font larger, I'm guessing that there is a simpler answer to do with viewport scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the following meta tag is included in your app html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

If you still feel that the buttons and text are to small (which the should be a personal preference) you could always try changing the css. Add a new rule like this:

```
body {
    font-size: 140% !important; //I believe 114% is default
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Magically, changing the font-size in the body css also scaled the buttons. Oddly, it didn't scale the button text, but I can live with that. Thx for the answer.

Comment: That is because the button size is probably styled with 'em' units but the text with px. Could be investigated using chrome for instance (right click button -> inspect element)